# Negative values for L*a*b* colorspace range in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently reworking the research of Gejima, Zhang and Nagata which is entitled Judgment on Level of Maturity for Tomato Quality Using L*a*b* Color Image Processing. I used OpenCV for the image processing part.

From the paper, a* in L*a*b* colorspace can have negative values while in OpenCV it is ranged from 0-255 for it to become 8 bit unsigned integer. How can I have the same reading of the L*a*b* that they have?

I have extracted the region of interest which is tomato, sum all the a* in the ROI and divided it by the number of over all pixels. But this will still give be wrong results since the range of a* in the L*a*b* colorspace in OpenCV is 255 and cannot be negative unlike in the paper. Furthermore, what is meant by G(36) in their paper? I have searched all over it in the internet but I cannot find it.

Comment: The best way to find the answer is to read the docs :D [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html), it tells you how the ranges of Lab colorspace will be... and also, it tells you that if the source image is 32 bit images the result will be as you wanted it (with the negative and so on)... convert it to float before changing the colorspace.

Comment: I believe StackOverflow isn't the best place to ask about a specific paper.  Without reading it I would guess that G(36) is a threshold for the green color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html), LAB range will depend on the type of the original image (uint8, float32, etc).

To accomplish your goal, you need to be sure the original image is float32.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = img.astype('float32')
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
lab = np.asarray(lab)
print (f'{lab.min()}, {lab.max()}')
```

Result:

```
-107.859375, 100.0
```